# Create my own Unique ID

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a my own unique ID in C# for each document in my NoSQL database but I am not too sure how I would do that?

My example UID would look something like this `######.entityType@######.contextName.worldName`

The hashes are alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Use a StringBuilder in order to concat your strings and adding the dot!

Comment: Unique to the world, or just unique to your population?

Comment: just unique to my population @ScottAdams

Comment: Why not use a Guid? Its designed to generate unique ids. It seems number of possiblities in your string is to low to not have any collisions.

Comment: Are you looking for unique or for unique/secure/encrypted UID? These are two different things. In the first case the `Guid.NewGuid()` method is sufficient, in the second case it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions here, but you could just generate a GUID, split the guid on the hyphen, use the parts of the guid in your user name.

Use a string builder to concatenate it all.

Here's a bit of sample code to give the idea (untested):

```
    Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
    String[] parts = g.ToString().Split('-');

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(parts[0]);
    sb.Append("entityType@");
    sb.Append(parts[1]);
    sb.Append(".contextName.worldName");

    string ID = sb.ToString();
```

This won't be GLOBALLY unique, but should give you fairly good range of uniqueness for your scenario.

To match your hash lengths above you could do this:

```
        String gString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-","");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(gString.Substring(0,6));
        sb.Append("entityType@");
        sb.Append(gString.Substring(6,6));
        sb.Append(".contextName.worldName");

        string ID = sb.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(ID);
```

Comment: Is grabbing the first 6/digits 6-11 characters of a GUID enough to guarantee uniqueness? Isn't the GUID unique only in it's completeness? Or is that "good enough" for local uniqueness? The real question then is why not just generate a random number if you're going to split the GUID?

Comment: I agree with @Brad, you may also want to verify your new entry is unique by doing a check. i assume that you keep all your entries in some data store. You call you name generating algorithm recursively until returns true on your uniqueness check.

Comment: Obviously, a full GUID is much better (more characters). However, the OP was wanting to generate a random userID that folowed a specific format. Using the GUID in this manner just made for a quick "Random" string generator. Hopefully he has a unique constraint on this field in his database and can regenerate if there is a constraint violation.

Answer (score 13):

Use [Guid.NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) method.

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
string uniqueID = guid.ToString();
```

[Globally unique identifier - WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

> A Globally Unique Identifier  is a unique reference number **used as
>   an identifier in computer software**. The term GUID typically refers
>   to various implementations of the universally unique identifier (UUID)
>   standard.

Answer (score 2):

The [SnowMaker](http://l.tath.am/snowmaker) library is good at giving you unique identifiers within a particular uniqueness scope.

Answer (score -2):

Do something like this to create it:

```
string characters = "abcdefghi123456";

string result = "";

Random random = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     result += characters[random.Next(0, characters.Length - 1)];
}
```

There's no assurance that it's going to be unique so you would have to check against your stored records in the DB before attempting to insert it, if that's what you're planning to do and be careful using upper and lower case as these may seen as the same in the database e.g. Abc may be the same as aBC